# Customize action bar from layout file at the time of loading

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a small problem with my action bar.

For my first application activity I want to use a special action bar layout: actionbar.xml and that's why I wrote a following code at the beginning of the `onCreate` method>

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
 actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
 actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
 View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);
 actionBar.setCustomView(cView);
```

It functions pretty well but while loading the application I still see the standart action bar of my activity theme. When the activity loading is completed, I see a customiyed application bar.

I tried to change the theme of my application and to set up theme for every activity:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/title"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:theme="@style/ActivityTheme"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/title">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".FirstActivity"
        android:theme="@style/ActivityTheme"
        android:label="@string/title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

where AppTheme and ActivitaTheme are defined as follows (because having no action bar during the loading is better than to have an ugly action bar):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="ActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

But this doesn't help.

Do you know how I can customize my action bar even for the loading time?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use instead android Toolbar https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

Comment: welcome...great it helped you